# Is the matrix $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As the title says. Is the matrices $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ hermitian (symmetric if $A$ is real)?

Comment: Hint: $(AB)^* = B^* A^*$

Comment: A matrix $M$ is Hermitian if $M^* = M$.  Take $M = A^* A$.  Does $(A^* A)^* = A^* A$?  Do you know how to express $(AB)^*$ in terms of $A^*$ and $B^*$?

Comment: Thanks! These hints really helped. Remember this from the lectures now. How could I not see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the definition of hermitian. This is not too hard, you just have to use that $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$. You don't need that $A$ is invertible in this proof, the statement is even true for $A$ not a square.