# Is it true that rank$(AA^{*}A) =$ rank$(A) ?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Is it true that $\operatorname{rank}(AA^{*}A) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$?

I know that $\operatorname{rank}(A^{*}A) = \operatorname{rank}(A)$, but I am not able to prove this one.
Neither I could find any counter example to disprove the statement.

Any hint$?$

Answer (score 4):

*Hints.*

1. Use singular value decomposition of $A$.
2. Alternatively, try to prove that $AA^\ast Ax=0$ if and only if $Ax=0$. For the forward implication, suppose $AA^\ast Ax=0$. Then $\|A^\ast Ax\|^2=x^\ast A^\ast AA^\ast Ax=0$. Hence $A^\ast Ax=0$. Use the same trick again to infer that $Ax=0$.

Comment: I've not studied about singular value decomposition. Moreover, of $AA^{*}Ax = 0$, then det$(AA^{*}A) = 0$ so it is not a full rank matrix. Does this imply that $A$ is also not a full rank matrix$?$

Comment: @Mathsaddict Yes, but then all you showed is that they are both singular, not that they have the same ranks. Moreover, the determinant argument doesn't apply when $A$ is not a square matrix. (I assumed that $A$ is rectangular in my answer.)

Comment: I understood the proof, still I have a doubt. What does this prove imply$?$ I mean, $AA^{*}Ax = 0$, iff $Ax=0$, how is this related to the equality of ranks$?$

Comment: @Mathsaddict That $AA^\ast Ax=0$ iff $Ax=0$ means that $AA^\ast A$ and $A$ have the same null spaces. Are you aware that in basic linear algebra, there is a theorem relating null space to matrix rank?

Comment: Yes, rank nullity theorem. Since $AA^{*}A$ and $A$ have same nullity, so their rank is same, by rank- nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Also $\text{rank}(AA^*)$ is the same as $\text{rank}(AA^*AA^*)$.

Comment: For hermitian matrices see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99630/is-the-matrix-aa-and-aa-hermitian and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix

Comment: Powers of Hermitian matrices don't change rank so all what is needed is to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties